# How to publish a local path on tomcat application?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I have a local folder that I save my files like:

C:\files\img1.png

C:\files\img2.png

C:\files\video.avi

What I want to do is publish these files on tomcat which is located under different directory. And access them from:

localhost/files/img1.png

localhost/files/img2.png

localhost/files/video.avi

Since I create these files with a different application, I don't want to copy files under [pathToTomcat]/webapps/files.

Is there a easy way to configure Tomcat to publish files, on a local file path, under some given url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `sever.xml` inside the `<Host>..</Host>` tag simply put:

```
<Context docBase="C:/files" path="/files" reloadable="true" />
```